# large dense low rank assignment problem

Tags: optimization

Is there a reasonably cheap method to solve the large, dense, low rank assignment problem $\max_\pi \sum_i A_{\pi i,i}$, where $\pi$ runs over all permutations.of $1:n$?

Here $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix of low rank $r$. Typical sizes would be  $n=10000~~$ (possibly much larger), $r=15$.

Comment: By $\pi i$ do you mean the product so that you're striding through the matrix for different $\pi$?

Comment: $\pi$ runs over all permutations.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $A_{\pi(i),i}$ then?

Comment: @JackPoulson: $\i(i)$ and $\pi i$ are two different notations for the image of $i$ under the permutation $\pi$.

Comment: Interesting question! Are you looking to exploit the low-rank structure just for *storage* reasons---that is, to save from having to form the entire matrix when applying a traditional assignment algorithm? Or are you looking for a way to exploit the low rank to accelerate the search?

Comment: Did you ever figure something out here?

Answer (score 3):

Since $A=R_1R_2^T$ with $R_1, R_2\in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, we have
$$
\sum_i A_{\pi i, i} = \sum_i (P_{\pi} A)_{i, i} = \text{trace}(P_{\pi}R_1R_2^T)
$$
where $P_{\pi}$ is the permutation matrix corresponding to $\pi$.

For any $\pi$, the trace can be computed as
$$
\text{trace}(P_{\pi}R_1R_2^T) = \sum_{i} \sum_{k} (P_{\pi}R_1)_{i,k} (R_2^T)_{k,i}
= \sum_{i,k} ((P_{\pi}R_1)\circ R_2)_{i,k}.
$$
(This quantity is also known as [Frobenius product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product), $P_{\pi}R_1:R_2$).

This idea doesn't take away the burden of having to go through all permutations and brute-force search for the maximum of all Frobenius products, and in fact is has the same arithmetic complexity as explicitly computing $A=R_1R_2^T$. However, it has much lower memory requirements since you never have to actually form $A$.